# Does the review queue's "filter" function combine tags using AND or OR?

Tags: support, reviewing

In any review queue, you can choose filters, which will streamline your reviews to only those from the tags you specify.

When entering multiple tags (example 2), does the review queue only select posts with *both* tags, or ones with *either* tag?
In other words, are tags in the filter area combined using AND or OR?

If they are normally combined using AND, how can I make the review queue combine them using OR?
If they are normally combined using OR, how can I make the review queue combine them using AND?

Comment: There are so few questions in need of review here that you don't really need to use filters; just Skip questions you aren't sure what to do with.

Comment: Yeah, I guess they were more for the more active sites on the network like [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are combined using OR; I couldn't find a source on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) but here's some proof:

[image]
<sub>this strange combination is just for science, of course</sub>

There's no way to make it an AND filter, but as @pppery notes, it's not meant for a site like this with small review queues. You'd miss almost all items.